# Adding ParentId to child element of same object type C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I am getting an element that contains a list of childs, of the same object.

I have to store them in a Database, and later on retrieve them back in the same structure. The problem is, that the list I get does not have any parentId, or anything that lets me keep track on the structure.

The element I get from the web service looks something like:

```
  public class StructureElementFacade
   {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Structure> Children { get; set; }

    public int ChildCount { get; set; }

    public int Lft { get; set; }

    public int Rgt { get; set; }
   }
```

And the element it should be translated to looks like:

```
  public class Structure
   {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Structure> Children { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public int ChildCount { get; set; }

    public int Lft { get; set; }

    public int Rgt { get; set; }

   }
```

I have tried to do something like:

```
StructureElementFacade Root = Service.GetInstance().GetWebService().getUserStructure(userId, true);

List<Structure> listofstructure = FromStructuresElementsToStructures(Root,new List<Structure>(),Root.Id);

  private List<Structure> FromStructuresElementsToStructures(StructureElementFacade root, List<Structure> list, int parentId )
    {
        var allstructures = list;
        foreach (var child in root.Children)
        {
            if (child.Children.Any())
            {
                FromStructuresElementsToStructures(child,list,child.Id);
            }
            else
            {
                allstructures.Add(
                new Structure
                {
                    Name = child.Name,
                    ParentId = parentId,
                    Lft = child.Lft,
                    Rgt = child.Rgt,
                    ThisId = child.Id,
                });
            }
        }
        return allstructures;
    }
```

But does not seem to work as I hoped.

Comment: wait... how do you know what the children are if they seem to miss their parent ID?

Comment: The child of the parent is within the parents List of children. So the parent knows it childs, but not the other way around. And that is why I need to set a ParentID. But as I dont have access to the web service, and modifying that I'm trying to do it by converting it to another object.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't paying attention and didn't see they came from a web service :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need recursion for this, since children can have children too.

```
List<Structure> convertAndSetParentIds(List<StructureElementFacade> inputItems, int? parentId)
{
     List<Structure> outputItems = new List<Structure>();

     foreach(StructureElementFacade facade in inputItems)
     {
          Structure newStructure = new Structure();
          newStructure.Id = facade.Id;
          newStructure.ParentId = parentId;
          newStructure.Left = facade.lft; 
          //etc... you can figure this bit out.

          // set all the properties based on facade object
          //except for the children, which is where we need recursion.
          newStructure.children = convertAndSetParentIds(facade.children, facade.Id);

          outputItems.add(newStructure);
     }
     return outputItems;
}
```

Now you can do this :

```
StructureElementFacade Root = Service.GetInstance().GetWebService().getUserStructure(userId, true);

List<Structure> listofstructure = convertAndSetParentIds(new List<StructureElementFacade>(){Root}, null);
```

The first (root) element in listofstructure will have a parentId of `NULL`, but the rest will have their parent ids set.

Keep in mind that for that to work, you will need to change the structure of your `Structure` object a little bit :

```
  public class Structure
   {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Structure> Children { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; } //this must be nullable, since the root item has no parent!

    public int ChildCount 
    { 
      get
      {
          //might as well do this:
          return Children == null ? 0 : Children.Count();
      } 
    }

    public int Lft { get; set; }

    public int Rgt { get; set; }

   }
```